# Xamarin app does not start after update in Apple App Store

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, app-store

I released version 1.1 of my app in App Store a few days ago. In this version I added a splash screen and shell and changed the name of the app bundle to info.plist. With this, the name of the app is displayed differently than version 1.0. Also i added a support e-mail button to send the user email to me. Before releasing the update app, I tested it on physical iphone and simulators. Everything worked wonderfully. Now the app update is published in the store and when I update the app and start it, the splash screen loads but nothing more. The app just crashes and I can't see why. My question:

How can I find out why the app crashes? Are there logs from App store? Does someone have an idea where the reason can be?
Many Thanks

Comment: If you put the link of the App in the Store we can try it.

Comment: Hello Bas. Yes of course. Thank you for the help

Comment: https://apps.apple.com/de/app/splity-tip-calculator/id1594211339

Comment: 1) if there was a consistent crash issue its very surprising Apple would approve it, 2) have you tried deleting the old version first, then installing the new one from the App Store?  3) crash reports are available if the user chooses to share them - look in XCode Organizer, 4) you should enable crash reporting and logging in your app, using a tool like appcenter.ms or raygun.io

Comment: Hi Jason thank you for the answer!!!  1) yes     2) yes.   3) i cant not read the reports.  4) thans for advice

Comment: have you tried deploying a local build using the RELEASE config to your device?

Comment: Hi Jason. The app crash also when i use RELEASE config. In DEBUG is no problem. I tested it now

Comment: if you can get it to crash locally using the Release config, then add some basic logging or use one of the previously mentioned tools

Comment: Yes its one step forward. Thank you for !! I check my configs now